# Upload a resume to a website using python selenium module

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, file-upload, automation

```
<a href="/resumes/new">upload a resume</a>
```

This is the html of the upload a resume button on a website.I was able to login to this website.Now i want to upload a resume using python selenium.

```
Attach_resume = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//a[@href="/resumes/new"]')
```

This is what I am trying to use for clicking the upload a resume button.But it throws an error 
    NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: //a[@href="/resumes/new"]

Is there anything that I am missing?I want to click that button and I want to upload a file to it.Please help me out.

Comment: Please provide the link to the website you are trying to access.

Comment: www.careerbuilder.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use below code and let me know the result:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.careerbuilder.com')
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//a[@href="/resumes/new"]'))).click()
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'resumeOnComp'))).click()
driver.find_element_by_id('ucResumeUpload_newFileUpload_inputResumeUpload').send_keys('/path/to/file')
```

Comment: NameError: name 'WebdriverWait' is not defined .It throws this error

Comment: Ooops, sorry, just a typo... Try again

Comment: What did you change?

Comment: `WebdriverWait` to `WebDriverWait`

Comment: Oh got it.Do i have to mention file name in the path along with the extension?

Comment: Absolute path to file with full name, e.g. `C:\\Files\\some_file.doc` or just file name if it located in same folder as your script

Comment: WebDriverException: Message: File not found: I get this error even though I am using absolute path

Comment: Hmm... can you show last code line with your absolute path to file? And also could you try to copy your file to the folder with your script and send just a file name without abs path?

Comment: driver.find_element_by_id('ucResumeUpload_newFileUpload_inputResumeUpload').send_keys('Desktop\resume1.docx') I have tried adding my file name both with and without absolute file name still it doesn't find my file.Have you tried uploading a file to the website?

Comment: No, I can't check it right now, but I'm quite sure that `Desktop\resum‌​e1.docx` is not the absolute path... Do you use `Linux` OS? Can you just drag'n'drop file to `Terminal` shell to see the absolute path to file?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134530/discussion-between-sai-and-andersson).

Answer (score 0):

Since I don't have a `careerbuilder` account I assume you were trying to access the resume page. I accessed the upload resume feature with no trouble.

```
chromedriver = "my_path"
os.environ["webdriver.chrome.driver"] = chromedriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver)
driver.get('https://www.careerbuilder.com/jobseeker/postnewresume.aspx?sslRedirectCnt=1&sc_cmp2=JS_Nav_PostRes')

driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="resumeOnComp"]').click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ucResumeUpload_newFileUpload_inputResumeUpload"]').click()
```

Answer (score 0):

This code works fine for me with Python 2.7 and Firefox 45.0.2

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver  = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://www.careerbuilder.com/")

element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[@href="/resumes/new"]')
print element.text
```

Comment: I also want to upload a file which is located on my desktop.Were you able to upload a file?